# javascript call a function of a plugin in instantiating it

Tags: javascript, function, jquery-plugins, private

I want to call a function which is in my plugin.

I overloaded a function but I want to call another function from it.

```
$("mySelector").Myplugin({
    My_function : function (){
        functioin_from_the_plugin();
    }
});
```

An error appears that says "Unknown function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the plugin allows you to hookup a startup event (e.g. onInit in the following, but it will be a *plugin-specific* name),

e.g.

```
$("mySelector").Myplugin({
    onInit: function (instance){
        instance.function_from_the_plugin();
    }
});
```

or (if the plugin retains the correct `this` when calling its method):

```
$("mySelector").Myplugin({
    onInit: function (){
        this.function_from_the_plugin();
    }
});
```

or, you have to *wait for the plugin to be created* before calling the method.

Depending on the way you created the plugin, the usual way would be something like this (which uses a string to specify the function name to call):

```
$("mySelector").Myplugin().Myplugin("function_from_the_plugin");
```

This creates the plugin, attaches it to the element, then calls a method on the plugin.

*Note: Without seeing the code for the plugin, these are only suggestions. Some plugin pattern are brain-dead and don't allow function calling*

Comment: Hi,

It's my first plugin.

I can give you the code but it continue to change.

I do not understand your first answer.

The second do not work and i thought to the third but do not like it.

You need my code?

On github is ok ?